# How to use e57xmldump.exe? (e57 to xml)

Tags: point-cloud-library, point-clouds, e57

I have .e57 file. And I try to convert it to .xml file using e57xmldump.exe, which I downloaded from this site:
http://www.libe57.org/data.html

I drag and drop my .e57 file in e57xmldump.exe. Then it's running in a terminal, doing some operations. And then nothing. It just closes...

Does anyone know how to use e57xmldump.exe properly?

Comment: Did you try to run it from the command line? For example, at the location of your .exe and run: `>e57xmldump  foo.e57 > foo.xml`? Is there an error showing up on the console then?

Comment: @GregoireCattan, yes you are right! To make it works it needs to open the terminal, go to a folder with the .e57 file and e57xmldump.exe, and do `>e57xmldump  NAME.e57 > NAME.xml`